# writing a formulation in a smaller form

Tags: notation

Is it possible to write this in a smaller form:
$(A \neq \emptyset) \vee (B \neq \emptyset)$ ?
is it for example mathematically correct to write it as:
$A \vee B \neq \emptyset$  ?

Comment: Are these sets, and are you talking about empty set? Then can write as $A\cup B \ne \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $A,B$ here are some sets. Then it is not correct to write $A\vee B\neq \emptyset$, because $\vee$ is not a set operation. $(A\neq \emptyset) \vee (B\neq\emptyset)$ is a logic statement, which is true if and only if $A\neq \emptyset$ or $B\neq \emptyset$, so $(A\neq \emptyset) \vee (B\neq\emptyset)\Leftrightarrow A\cup B\neq \emptyset$

Comment: Of course, $A \cup B \neq \varnothing$ might be the shorter form you want...